# R font size change not working

Tags: r, fonts, r-markdown

I'm trying to change my subtitle font size in R, but it is not working. I read you had to change the cex.sub.

```
mosaic(table, shade=TRUE, colorize = T, main = "$$$$", sub = "$$$$", cex.sub = 0.5)
```

as you can see the title falls outside of the window, neither increasing or decreasing the cex makes a difference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try `sub_gp=gpar(fontsize=11)` (the default size is 18) or `sub_gp=gpar(cex=0.5)` instead of `cex.sub=0.5`